# Problems connecting Visual Studio to Azure. target machine refused connection?

Tags: azure

I have been uploading to Azure for at least six months. From this afternoon onwards I now get messages like this:

There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net/xxxxxx/services/hostedservices that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

Can anyone give me advice on what's wrong. I tried to upload a new management certificate. That worked fine but then said "authentication error".

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. It doesn't matter if the Fiddler is ON/OFF or the computer has been restarted - the problem is in Fiddler Option.

The msg was: **"Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"**

Go=> Fiddler/Tools/Fiddler Option/

Connection Tab:

- make sure that "Allow remote computers to connect" is NOT checked
- make sure that "Monitor all connections" is NOT checked

Here is a sample video:
http://screencast.com/t/S8y9NbpveSjd

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Can you please check if Fiddler is running or not? Normally when you run Fiddler it acts as a proxy and listens at port 8888.

Hope this helps.

Comment: saved my day! cheers fiddler was not running but proxy setting were in place in IE... set them to detect automatically and good to go...

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue. When I use Visual Studio 2013 to download an extension. It can not connect the remote site.

Assi.NET's method doesn't work. Which means **unchecked** "Allow remote computers to connect" and "Monitor all connections" still can't get rid of the problem.

To fix it, I find in the machine config file, I added something to enable default proxy. Make sure you **DISABLE** it.
The correct code is:

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy
            enabled = "false"
            useDefaultCredentials = "true">
    <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Where is that Machine Config file located?